# How to properly use Foundation4 while using WordPress Content Management Systems?

Tags: php, wordpress, zurb-foundation

So I'm using the Foundation 4 framework. I created a test landing page. I had then created  a page template from this landing page (the page is called simply as page.php).

However, for some reason my page.php through WordPress isn't conforming to what I wanted it to look like ( I have provided a screen shot to show what it is coming out as).

All my css and js files are being referenced correctly through correct file paths (see code below). Everything that the foundation css folder consisted of, I had transferred it to the wp-content/css folder (as well as the js and images folders too).

So I'm not sure as to why my page is coming out the way it is. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's what my code looks like (ignore the extra/random comments, after all it is for testing):

```
<?php /* Template Name: VM

*/?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title> VenziMedia Foundation 4</title>

  <!-- If you are using CSS version, only link these 2 files, you may add app.css to use for your overrides if you like. -->

  <!-- 

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/css/normalize.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/css/foundation.css" />
  <script src="lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

  <script src="lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/js/jquery.txt"></script>
  <script src="lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
  --> 

  <?php 
  include('lol/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php');
  include('lol/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php');

  wp_register_style( 'normalize-css', 'lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/css/normalize.css');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'normalize-css', 'lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/css/normalize.css');
  ?>

  <?php
  include('lol/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php');
  include('lol/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php');

  wp_register_style( 'foundation-css', 'lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/css/foundation.css');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation-css', 'lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/css/foundation.css');
  ?>

  <?php
  include('lol/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php');
  include('lol/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php');

  wp_register_script( 'foundation-min', 'lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/js/foundation.min.js' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-min', 'lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/js/foundation.min.js' );
  ?>

  <?php
  include('lol/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php');
  include('lol/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php');

  wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/js/jquery.txt' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/js/jquery.txt' );
  ?>

  <?php
  include('lol/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php');
  include('lol/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php');

  wp_register_script( 'mod-js', 'lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'mod-js', 'lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js' );
  ?>

</head>
<body>

  <!-- body content here -->

  <nav class="top-bar">
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="vm.php">VenziMedia</a></h1>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="right">

        <li class="divider"></li>

        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="vm.php">Home</a></h1>
        </li>

        <li class="divider"></li>

        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="vm.php">Services</a></h1>
        </li>

        <li class="divider"></li>

        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="vm.php">Advertisers</a></h1>
        </li>

        <li class="divider"></li>

        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="vm.php">Technology</a></h1>
        </li>

        <li class="divider"></li>

        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="#" data-reveal-id="second-modal">Contact</a></h1>
        </li>

        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="has-form">
            <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" class="tiny button">LOGIN/SIGN UP</a>
        </li>
    </section>
    </ul>
  </nav>


  <br><br><br>

<!-- ======================== ORBIT===================== -->
<div style="width: 80%; margin:0 auto">
    <ul data-orbit>
        <li>
            <img src="1.jpg" />
            <div class="orbit-caption">you this is the first slideeee</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="1.jpg" />
            <div class="orbit-caption">why don't you just send us money?</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="1.jpg" />
            <div class="orbit-caption">how much wood could a wood chuck chuck, if a wood chuck could chuck wood?</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<br><br><br>
<!-- =======ORBIT END======= -->

<!-- =======14 ======= -->

<div style="text-align:center">
<a href="#" class="large button expand">START YOUR FREE 14-DAY TRIAL! </a>
</div>

<!-- =======14 day END ======= -->

<!--===== 2 PANELLS ====  -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <div class="panel">
            <h6>LOCAL/SMB</h6>
            <p>Learn how VenziMedia can help your business advertise on a local and national level with strategic ad solutions.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <div class="panel">
            <h6>AGENCY/BRAND</h6>
            <p>Contact VenziMedia today to see how we can add value to you or your clients Brand and get a better ROI.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- ====== 2 PANELLS END ====  -->

<!-- ===== WHY VENZI MEDIA ====== -->
<div style="text-align:center">
    <a href="#" class="large button">WHY VENZIMEDIA?</a>
</div>
<!-- ===== WHY VENZI MEDIA END ====== -->


<div class="row">
    <div class="small-4 columns">
        <div class="panel">
        <!-- Content here -->
        <h6>You check this out man</h6>
        <p>we got some cool stuff at venziMedia !</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-4 columns">
        <ul class="pricing-table">
            <li class="title">Standard</li>
            <li class="price">$99.99</li>
            <li class="description">An awesome description</li>
            <li class="bullet-item">1 Database</li>
            <li class="bullet-item">5GB Storage</li>
            <li class="bullet-item">20 Users</li>
            <li class="cta-button"><a class="button" href="#">Buy Now</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="small-4 columns">
        <div class="panel">
        <!-- Content here -->
        <h6>some more cool stuff</h6>
        <p> you know like venzimedia !this is some random words</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


    <script>
      document.write('<script src=lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/js/vendor/'
        + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
        + '.js><\/script>');
    </script>

  <script>
  document.write('<script src=' +
  ('__proto__' in {} ? 'lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/js/vendor/zepto' : 'lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/js/vendor/jquery') +
  '.js><\/script>')
  </script>


  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>

 <!-- =========== FIRST REVEAL ======= -->
 <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
     <form>
         <fieldset>
             <legend>Fieldset</legend>

             <div class="row">
                 <div class="large-12 columns">
                     <label>Input Label</label>
                     <input type="text" placeholder="large-12.columns">
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <label>Input Label</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="large-4.columns">
            </div>

            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <label>Input Label</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="large-4.columns">
            </div>

        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <div class="row collapse">
                <label>Input Label</label>
            <div class="small-9 columns">
                <input type="text" placeholder="small-9.columns">
            </div>
                <div class="small-3 columns">
                    <span class="postfix">.com</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="row">
     <div class="large-12 columns">
       <label>Textarea Label</label>
        <textarea placeholder="small-12.columns"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
  </form>
  </div>
 <!-- ========== FIRST REVEAL END ====== -->

 <!-- ========= 2ND REVEAL ===== -->
 <div id="second-modal" class="reveal-modal">
    <div class="section-container tabs" data-section="tabs">
        <section class="active">
            <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Phone/Email</a></p>
            <div class="content" data-section-content>
                <b>Sales #: </b>123-456-789<br>
                <b>Tech #: </b>232-453-564<br>
                <b>Email (tech): </b>tech@Venzimedia.com<br>
                <b>Email (sales): </b>sales@Venzimedia.com<br>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section>
            <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Adress</a></p>
            <div class="content" data-section-content>
                <b>123 Easy St.</b><br>
                <b>Hayward, CA</b><br>
                <b>94509</b><br>
                <b>USA</b>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section>
            <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Social</a></p>
            <div class="content" data-section-content>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/VenziMedia?ref=br_tf">Check our Facebook!</a><br>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/venzimedia">Check our Twitter!</a>
            </div>
        </section>


    </div>
</div>
 <!-- ========== 2ND REVEAL END ==== -->



</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to code everything from zero for foundation.

Some good people have already done the dirty work for you.

Check [HERE](http://zurbpress.wpprofs.com/) or [HERE](https://github.com/drewsymo/Foundation) [HERE](http://320press.com/wp-foundation/)..

Ready made themes for foundation - a good starting point .
You even have plugins like [THIS](http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-foundation-shortcodes/) that will help you if you do want to code ..

But to directly answer your question - off the top of my head - your CSS and scripts are inserted wrong ,and with wrong paths.

In WP you will have to use [`wp_register_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) functions , and the same for styles [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) and [`wp_register_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style)

**Edit I**

After comment :

```
I had to un-answer this because I had made the necessary changes to the file and still it did not work, I will make an edit in my post above for you to see the changes.
```

Dude , I think you got all all wrong...
By your code above , I can understand that you have very little experience in `wordpress` development , and `PHP` in general..

If you insist on writing your own theme from Zero, I suggest you get your self familiarized with some basic concepts ...

The code you have inserted is all wrong , and in the wrong place .. it needs to go into `functions.php` and needs to be something like so :

```
/**
 * Enqueue Scripts and Styles for Front-End
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 'foundation_assets' ) ) :

function foundation_assets() {

    if (!is_admin()) {

        /** 
         * Deregister jQuery in favour of ZeptoJS
         * jQuery will be used as a fallback if ZeptoJS is not compatible - uncomment at will
         * @see foundation_compatibility & http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html
         */
        // wp_deregister_script('jquery');

        // Load JavaScripts
        wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation.min.js', null, '4.0', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js', null, '2.1.0');
        if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( "comment-reply" );

        // Load Stylesheets
        wp_enqueue_style( 'normalize', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/normalize.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/foundation.min.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'app', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('foundation') );

        // Load Google Fonts API
        wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' );

    }

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foundation_assets' );

endif;
```

You do not need

```
include('lol/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php');
  include('lol/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php');
```

And certainly not `6` times ( in PHP , including one time is enough ...)

Also , the following line

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'lol/wordpress/wp-content/foundation-5/js/jquery.txt' )
```

is wrong as jquery is embaded in wp and needs only to be called

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
```

Then you will need to initialize

```
/**
 * Initialise Foundation JS
 * @see: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 'foundation_js_init' ) ) :

function foundation_js_init () {
    echo '<script>$(document).foundation();</script>';
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'foundation_js_init', 50);

endif;
```

All that will of course work only if you have the correct [wp_head()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) and [wp_footer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) functions in your theme files , AND if you included the header and footer correctly , AND made the correct Folder structure , AND ...

..And I can go on and on, but honestly, I do not think I can give you a crash course in [wordpress theme development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files) AND [PHP](http://php.net/) in only one answer here on SE ...

You will need to google for yourself in order to learn - and mind you , I do not try to encourage you from doing that - It is well worth the time invested .

But writing the first wordpress theme from ground up require certain expertise, and that is why I suggested you before to download some empty themes - read and learn from them .

Myself (and I am sure many other good people here on SE ) will be more than happy to "walk you through" the process by answering specific question - but you must build some ground to stand on , otherwise it becomes impossible to answer ...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but the thing is that I want to code everything from scratch. Also, what would be the correct paths? Thanks.

Comment: the correct way is using the functions I wrote above .They will provide the right path ( and ONLY they in wordpress ) read the codex (links posted )and implement at will ( if you want to code from zero..)

Comment: I had to un-answer this because I had made the necessary changes to the file and still it did not work, I will make an edit in my post above for you to see the changes.